# How to add multiple Headers files path in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile, compilation, include, include-path, kbuild

I am trying to compile uleds.c driver and this driver includes multiple files existing under this path :

> /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/src/kernel/include/linux

I want now to modify my Makefile and add this path so I can compile correctly uleds.c

This is my Makefile :

```
#CC=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv7-a -marm -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a5 --sysroot=/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi
#CC="gcc"

obj-m += uleds.o

KERNEL_SOURCE := /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/lib/modules/4.14.73-linux4sam-6.0-dirty

default:
        ${CC} ${KERNEL_SOURCE} uleds.c

clean:
        ${CC} $(INC) ${KERNEL_SOURCE} clean
```

Any suggestions for that ? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be an attempt at a kbuild file,.

You should not be manually compiling the file yourself using your `default` rule.  Instead, you should be running the kernel's makefile, and have it compile the driver based on `obj-m` and friends.

Your makefile would look like so:

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)

ccflags-y += -I some/other/dir
obj-m += uleds.o

else

# default to build against running kernel if KDIR not
# specified:
KDIR ?= /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build

default:
     $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD

endif
```

If you call make from the driver's directory, it will in turn call make from your kernel directory, which will know everything about the kernel and will be able to properly build your module.

Notice that by default, the built-in kernel's clean target will remove all generated `*.[oas]` files, so no need for a special `clean` target.  Also, by default, the kernel's makefile will include its own `include` directories, so you likely don't need to do anything special for that.  In case you do need to include from somewhere else, you can add a `-I` directive to the `ccflags-y` as shown in the example.

See [Linux Kernel Makefiles](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt) and [Building External Modules](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt) for details.

Comment: In fact, I am working on Linux host machine and i am trying to cross compile a driver which will be loaded in another Linux kernel version different from my host machine. For that I am using `arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc (GCC) 7.3.0` cross compiler in order to build uleds.ko module . In this makefile i defined the path of my the target mahine linux kernel and all the includes existing

Comment: Ok, you'll need to point `KDIR` at your kernel's source tree, so it builds the driver for that.   The include dir you mentioned looks to be one of the standard include directories, so it should be on the generated command line, but if it's not, you can always manually specify it.

Comment: I modified the Makefile to that : `ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)

ccflags-y += -I /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/src/kernel/include/linux
obj-m += uleds.o

else

# default to build against running kernel if KDIR not
# specified:
KDIR ?= /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/lib/modules/4.14.73-linux4sam-6.0-dirty

default:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD

endif `
Than i tape `make` but this shows me another errors

Comment: make -C /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/lib/modules/4.14.73-linux4sam-6.0-dirty M=$PWD
make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/lib/modules/4.14.73-linux4sam-6.0-dirty'
make[1]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/lib/modules/4.14.73-linux4sam-6.0-dirty'
Makefile:13: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2

Comment: Is there a makefile at `/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/lib/modules/4.14.73-linux4sam-6.0-dirty`?    The root of your kernel source directory should have a Makefile.

Comment: No there is not, I thought that this is the correct path of my kernel source directory

Comment: When you build the kernel, what directory do you build from?   The directory will have several subdirectories including arch,crypto,include,mm, etc, along with a Makefile, and a .config file.

Comment: You rock my friend ! it's done now ! I changed my kernel source directory and it works now! Thank you

Comment: Hello friend, I read Linux kernel Makefiles and Building external modules which you recommended for me But i really did not get the use of IF and ELSE statements. Can't get the use of them! Please can you clarify me this in a simple way

Comment: Typically when you build a kernel driver, you build using the kernel's main makefile, which includes the driver's kbuild makefile.   ( kernel_makefile ==include==> driver_makefile ).  But, if you want to build from the driver's directory, you need it to call the kernel_makefile, which then includes it:  ( driver_makefile ==calls==> kernel_makefile ==include==> driver_makefile ).   The driver makefile is used twice in this scenario.   The `ifdef` is used to prevent things like namespace contamination, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is:

```
${CC} -I/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/src/kernel/include/linux uleds.c
```

Try reading the following to get familiar with other GCC (compiler) options: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options

Comment: KERNEL_SOURCE is not the folder of the includes file. It's an other path for the Linux kernel and not the includes . As i see so i will add another variable where i define the path and i add this : -I${variable}

Comment: Ah, I see. Corrected my answer. but -I <the path with headers> is the answer.

Comment: This is a kernel build file, which means the module should be built from the kernel build system.   The `-I` would likely solve OP's first compile error, but they would run into other issues afterwards.